# Performance of Vectorize() on rcpp function?

Tags: r, rcpp

I was wondering if applying Vectorize() on an rcpp function would be potentially bad from a performance perspective? For example, given code like this:

```
double powerC(double x) {
  return x * x;
}
```

If I wanted a vectorized version of this function (or perhaps even more complex functions), and did something like below:

```
powerC2 <- Vectorize(powerC)
```

Would it be significantly worse performance-wise to do so, compared to simply vectorizing it in the c++ code itself?

Thank you.

Comment: Most likely it's better to do in c++. But it really all depends on exactly what your function does. It would be better to test yourself with your specific use case. It's hard to make very broad generalizations about how fast code will run in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

So I just tested the version above against the code below:

```
Rcpp::NumericVector powerV(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
  return x * x;
}
```

I benchmarked the difference:

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark("powerC" = {powerC2(1:10000)},
 "powerV" = {powerV(1:10000)})
```

and powerC2 took 2.641 secs, whereas powerV took 0.003. So it would seem to definitely be slower compared to vectorizing it in c++.

Comment: `Vectorize` is just a wrapper to `do.call(mapply, ...)`. You can look at the code at your console. It's hard to believe that it should be faster to use `Vectorize` over properly written Rcpp coding.